# fix htaccess in publichtml causing error 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have been having persistent and intermittent 500 internal server error on my site www . lemmymorgan . com.  This error stays as it is without clearing unless i delete or rename my .htaccess file inside my public_html folder. I notice some codes / rewites on my .htaccess file just minutes after renaming.

my site is wordpress and the basic htacess contents used to be:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Seconds after .htaccess new .htaccess creation, the codes will change to:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^([^\d\/]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-[0-9]+.*-.*-.*-.*-.*-.*-.*[0-9]+..*$ ?$1$3=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
    </IfModule>


and currently, i have a more complicated code in my .htaccess file that led to the 500 error few hours ago:

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/([^\d\/]+)([0-9]+)-.*-.*-.*-.**\/.*[0-9]+\/$ ?$2$1=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/([^\d\/]+)([0-9]+).*-.*-.*-.*-.*-.*-.*-[0-9]+.*-.*-.*-.*-[0-9]+-.*-.*-\/$ ?$2$1=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/([^\d\/]+)([0-9]+)-.*-.*\/.*[0-9]+\/$ ?$2$1=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/([^\d\/]+)([0-9]+)\/$ ?$2$1=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/([^\d\/]+)([0-9]+)-.*-[0-9]+.*-.*-.*-.*-.*-.*-.*-.*\/$ ?$2$1=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteRule ^([^\d\/]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+-.*\/$ ?$1$3=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteRule ^([^\d\/]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)\/\(.*\)-.*-.*-.*-[0-9]+-.*-.*\/.*[0-9]+\/$ ?$1$3=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteRule ^([^\d\/]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)\/$ ?$1$3=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/([^\d\/]+)([0-9]+).*-.*%[0-9]+\/$ ?$2$1=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteRule ^([^\d\/]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-[0-9]+-.*[0-9]+-.*\/.*[0-9]+\/$ ?$1$3=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteRule ^([^\d\/]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-[0-9]+-.*-.*-.*-[0-9]+-[0-9]+-.*-.*\/$ ?$1$3=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/([^\d\/]+)([0-9]+)-.*-.*\/$ ?$2$1=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/([^\d\/]+)([0-9]+)-.*\/$ ?$2$1=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/([^\d\/]+)([0-9]+)-.*-.*-.*\)\/.*[0-9]+\/$ ?$2$1=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/([^\d\/]+)([0-9]+).*\/$ ?$2$1=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteRule ^([^\d\/]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-.*-.*-.*\/$ ?$1$3=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/([^\d\/]+)([0-9]+)-.*-.*-.*-.*\/$ ?$2$1=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/([^\d\/]+)([0-9]+).*-.*-.*-\/$ ?$2$1=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteRule ^([^\d\/]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-[0-9]+-[0-9]+-.*-.*-.*-[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+\/.*[0-9]+\/$ ?$1$3=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/([^\d\/]+)([0-9]+)-.*-.*-.*-.*-[0-9]+.*-.*\/[0-9]+\/$ ?$2$1=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/([^\d\/]+)([0-9]+)\/.*[0-9]+\/$ ?$2$1=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteRule ^([^\d\/]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)\/\(.*\)-.*-.*-.*-.*[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+-.*-.*-.*-[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+-.*\/.*[0-9]+\/$ ?$1$3=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/([^\d\/]+)([0-9]+)-\(.*[0-9]+-.*\)-.*-.*-.*-.*-.*\/$ ?$2$1=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/([^\d\/]+)([0-9]+)-.*-.*-.*-.*-.*-.*\/$ ?$2$1=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/([^\d\/]+)([0-9]+)-.*\/.*[0-9]+\/$ ?$2$1=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/([^\d\/]+)([0-9]+).*-.*%[0-9]+-.*-.*-.*-.*-.*-.*[0-9]+-[0-9]+-.*-.*-.*\/$ ?$2$1=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteRule ^([^\d\/]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+-.*-.*\/.*[0-9]+\/$ ?$1$3=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/([^\d\/]+)([0-9]+).*-.*-[0-9]+-.*-.*-.*-.*-.*-.*\/$ ?$2$1=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/([^\d\/]+)([0-9]+)-.*-.*-.*\/.*[0-9]+\/$ ?$2$1=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/([^\d\/]+)([0-9]+)-.*-.*-.*-.*-.*-.*-.*-.*-.*\/$ ?$2$1=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/([^\d\/]+)([0-9]+)-[0-9]+\/$ ?$2$1=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/([^\d\/]+)([0-9]+)-.*-.*-.*\/$ ?$2$1=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteRule ^([^\d\/]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+\/.*[0-9]+\/$ ?$1$3=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteRule ^([^\d\/]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-.*-\(.*-.*\/$ ?$1$3=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/([^\d\/]+)([0-9]+)\)\/$ ?$2$1=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/([^\d\/]+)([0-9]+)-.*-.*-.*-.*-[0-9]+\/$ ?$2$1=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([^\d\/]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-[0-9]+.*-.*-.*-.*-.*-.*-.*[0-9]+..*$ ?$1$3=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
</IfModule>
```

Please help me solve this problem as am not a geek in php coding. just help me correct the ocee so that i replace or teach me what to do exactly.

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked

Comment: am afraid no indication that my site was hacked. i only receive 500 error, it started without any modifications to my site. My host says they find nothing wrong with my site, site not blacklisted by google. BUt i do not know why my site is crashing and what is causing it

Comment: Well, if my `.htaccess` was modified (and in such way) without my control, and site was unreachable because of error 500, I would sure be less calm than you :)

Comment: Still, I am indeed not a wordpress expert, so this might be a usual thing

Comment: that is why am here. if i were to be calm, i wont be desperate to get a solution. Also let me quickly add that immediately i delete the .htaccess file under public_html, my site will be back fully withut any error at last for the next couple of days before going off again. it is a recurring thing currently.